# NiFi: Pass attribute from flow file to multiple files in another flow

Tags: apache-nifi

Is any ability in NiFi to take every file of one flow and merge it with another, that contains only one file?

In that way, I want apply the same attribute to all flow files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging flowfiles modifies the *content* of the flowfiles. If you want to modify an *attribute* of one (or more) flowfiles, use the `UpdateAttribute` processor. If the value of the attribute you want to apply is dynamic, you can use the `LookupAttribute` processor to retrieve the value from a lookup service and apply it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Andy! LookupAttribute seems interesting. Can I configure it to look after the attribute from another flow?

Comment: You'll need to set a value from the "other" flow into some kind of shared state and then look it up. Abdelkrim Hadjidj wrote a [nice article](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Data-flow-enrichment-with-NiFi-part-2-LookupAttribute/ta-p/247072) on performing this kind of data enrichment.